# Is Drools.net free version or licened?

Tags: drools

I am working on implementing business rules. We would like to evaluate different open source product for business rule engine. Could any one tell me is drools.net free or licenced?

Comment: Google? Yahoo? Need assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Drools itself (java and other JVM languages) is [Apache Licensed](https://www.drools.org/code/license.html) which is very permissive open source license (free to use, free to modify, etc), see "apache license layman explanation".

Drools.net (.NET, C# etc) I don't know - does that still exist? I see most .NET users calling the KIE Execution Server through REST to do rules.

Comment: Do you means Drools.NET no one is using and instead uesr are calling KIE executing server?

Comment: There is nothing like drools.net, Drools and .net are two different things. You can deploy rules in kie-server and execute those rules through REST API from .net client